# Синоніми щоб назвати або окликнути дитину

Tags: вибір-слова, синоніми

Я знаю жартівливо-сварливі - `бешкетник` і `пустун`, а також нейтральні - `доню`,`сину` та `дитино`. Потрібні широковживані варіанти синонімів різноманітного емоційного і змістовного забарвлення.

Comment: Іншими словами, ви шукаєте слова, які *мають* «різноманітне» емоційне та змістовне забарвлення, але не вказуєте, яке са́ме (позитивне, негативне, жартівливе тощо). Тобто, відповідей існує необмежений список. Asking for open-ended list is considered off topic as it leads to opinionated answers and OP's inability to chose the accepted one.

Comment: Є дитина. Я про неї можу говорити чи звертатися до неї використовуючи її ім'я, а можу замінити іншим іменником. Які саме іменники найчастіше використовують люди, які спілкуються українською з дитинства?

Comment: Define "найчастіше". У моїх родичів на селі до усіх дітей і підлітків *найчастіше* звертаються «Пилипчук», на честь Пилипа, який мав чи не дві дюжини дітей по всьому селу. Пилипа вже нема, *«найчастіше»* лишилося.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Навряд чи є сталий перелік таких звернень. У залежності - які казки ви розповідали, які стосунки з дитиною, які яскраві спільні події відбулися. Ось як я звертався до своїх синів:

```
коник, стрибунець,
жеребчик,
сокіл, соколик
серденько,
телесик
```

Answer (score 1):

[«Словники України on-line» від українського мовно-інформаційного фонду](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) пропонують такі синоніми до слова «пустун»:

> **ПУСТУ́Н** (той, хто любить пустувати), **БЕШКЕ́ТНИК**, **ЗБИТОЧНИК** [**ЗБИТОШНИК**] *розм.*, **ШИ́БЕНИК** *розм.*, **ЖИРУ́Н** *розм.*, **ПОСТРИБУ́Н** *розм.*, **ШАЛАПУ́Т** *розм.*, **ШАЛАПУ́ТНИК** *розм.*, **ШКО́ДА** *розм.*, **ХАЛАМИ́ДНИК** *розм.*, **ПАЛИ́ВОДА** *підсил. розм.*, **ПАЛИ́СВІТ** *підсил. розм.*, **ГАРЦІВНИ́К** *діал.*, **ШАЛИВІР** *діал.*, **ГАЙДАБУ́РА** *діал.*, **ГАЛАБУ́РДНИК** *діал.*
>
> <далі йдуть приклади вживання, які я не наводжу>

Звісно, не всі вони є загальновживаними або прийнятними для сучаних дітей, але якісь цілком можна застосувати.